# Releasing big node module from memory

Tags: node.js, memory

I'm loading a big js module into memory and I want to release it when is no longer needed to free RAM.

The code I am using to test is like this:

```
var lex = require('./lex.js'); //Big module (10M array)

setInterval(() => console.log(process.memoryUsage()), 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
    lex = null;
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./lex.js')];
}, 5000);

// this script outputs each second
// { rss: 151756800, heapTotal: 131487520, heapUsed: 108843840 }
// { rss: 151760896, heapTotal: 131487520, heapUsed: 108850024 }
// ...
// and after 5 seconds there is no change
```

After 5 seconds the process is still using the same memory as after the initial module load.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Delete Require cache will help you to load once again the content not from the cache ,as of me it will not delete or free up your memory

Comment: He knows it doesn't work. This is not really an answer. Do you know what **will** work?

Comment: Hello rudie, if you require a lib in a var and if you   delete the var probably then the var have no use,but if you assign a global var and if you declared its value inside the require function ,once you delete the require cache the assigned value will gone,it may help think so :)

Comment: @krishnakumarsekar sorry it didn't help, but thank you